What is the connection between Logical Effort and Mobility? MOSFET
let us say we have some kind of CMOS circuit.
We are given \$\mu_n=x\$ and \$\mu_p=y\$
But suddenly, \$\mu_n=2x\$ and \$\mu_p=2y\$
can we say that the Logical Effort and electrical effort are unchanged since:
\$R\propto \frac 1 K\$ as \$K\propto \mu\$.
Now, is it true for only linear state in which \$R= \frac {V_ds} {I_ds}\$
Or its true for all states? please explain. Thanks!

Logical effort is defined with respect to a unit inverter. The sizing of that unit inverter usually follows the mobility ratio or square root of that. Doubling both mobilities does not change your unit inverter sizing, just makes it faster. Thus, it also does not change the logical effort for any gate.

Thanks! Answered my question perfectly.
